# Ionic list dividers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a list in Ionic 3 framework, but it's displayed without any dividers and that is confusing, because Ionic documentation says that "By default, all lists will be styled with divider lines". This is my code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let section of sections" (click)="goToSection(section)">
          {{section.name}}
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

And this is the output:

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please check of divider is applying or not

Comment: You will have to be more specific.

Comment: have you added any custom css?

Answer (score 1):

Is your list inside a card element, if so there will be no list dividers.

See here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-list

Comment: Thank you, but that's still not it.